# GitLab Pages custom domain allow www

Tags: dns, hosting, jekyll, gitlab, cloudflare

What do I need to do in order for my GitLab pages site (Jekyll) to be accessed under `www.mydomain.com` not just `mydomain.com`? I have SSL through CloudFlare.

In my DNS I have: 
`mydomain.com A 104.208.235.32`

and CNAME points to `myname.gitlab.io`, and `www` points to `myname.gitlab.io`

Do I need to create a subdomain of `www` and point those to GitLab as well? I'd like my site to be without `www` in the url, but if a user types in `www` they should still be able to access the site.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The configurations in the question are correct, what I didn't do is add both `mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` as domains in GitLab (Settings icon > Pages > New Domain).

GitLab then directs traffic to both www and the naked domain when both domains are listed.

Comment: I would choose for www. or the naked domain, and not use both. Duplicate content and split page rank could occur when you use both. Might not be true though...

Comment: I had this exact problem. I had to set my www domain on git lab pages too (wasn't obvious), then I had to add two A records (one for @ and one for www with the gitlab ip), and then I had to add a CNAME for www to <repo>.gitlab.io. Now it's good, thanks!

Comment: So it's not possible to just add a CNAME for `www` as an alias of `mydomain.com`?

Comment: GitLab Pages docs section [Redirecting www.domain.com to domain.com with Cloudflare](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/getting_started_part_three.html#redirecting-wwwdomaincom-to-domaincom-with-cloudflare) recommends a 301 redirect (Page Rules in CloudFlare)

Answer (score 0):

Create a subdomain www.example.com and point that to gitlab. Then detect www in the URL and redirect to non-www.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
if ( document.domain.substring(0,4) != 'www.' ) {
    window.location = document.URL.replace("//","//www."); 
}
</script>
```

Source: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/26846703/redirect-non-www-to-www-url-using-Javascript.html

Comment: Unfortunately [I get this error](http://imgur.com/a/7rpiA) when I try to create the subdomain with `www`, any ideas?

Comment: won't solve the issue, it is a DNS misconfiguration. Redirection on the client side would not solve it.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me:

Add `www` subdomain as a separate page to your GitLab pages domains and please follow the instructions in the documentation:

[Set up DNS Records for both root and subdomains (www)](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/pages/custom_domains_ssl_tls_certification/index.html#for-both-root-and-subdomains)